# Redefining image height with renewcommand

Tags: graphics, size

I have defined `\secimage`as the image at my section titlepage:

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
  %\centering
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{\secimage}\\
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
```

And for each section I redefine the image using `\renewcommand{\secimage}{figureofchoice}`. But in one of the sections I would like also to redefine the width/height. I tryed `\renewcommand{\secimage}[heigth=4cm]{image}` like the documentation of renewcommand defines the options, but I have a compiling error.

If someone could please say what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code suggests a change in your notation. Instead of `\renewcommand{\secimage}{<image>}`, you use `\setsecimage{[<options>]{<image>}}` where it allows you to specify additional options.

```
\newcommand{\setsecimage}[1]{\gdef\secimagedetail{#1}}% Store section image detail
\let\secimagedetail\relax% Default definition of section image detail

\AtBeginSection{
  \begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
      \ifx\secimagedetail\relax\else % If section image exists
        \expandafter\includegraphics\secimagedetail \\
      \fi
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
  \end{frame}
  \let\secimagedetail\relax% Remove section image detail
}
```

with a typical usage resembling

```
\setsecimage{[width=50pt]{example-image}}

\section{A section}

\section{Another section}

\setsecimage{{example-image}}

\section{Final section}
```

If your `\setsecimage` does not include any `<options>` (for the final section in the above code), you still have to "double-brace" the `<image>` argument, as in `\setsecimage{{<image>}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Define a `\setsecimage` command with the same syntax as `\includegraphics`. The trick is that it redefines another macro.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
  %\centering
  \addsecimage\\
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand{\setsecimage}[2][width=4cm]{%
  \renewcommand{\addsecimage}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\addsecimage}{} % initialize

\begin{document}

\setsecimage{example-image}

\section{Normal}

\setsecimage[width=2cm]{example-image-a}

\section{Small}

\end{document}
```

[image]